# Different perl verions not sharing the installed rpms

Tags: linux, perl, coredump, openwsman

I have RHEL 32 bit OS, I had installed libwsman1 and openwsman-perl rpm to use wsman queries in my perl script. I have two versions of perl installed - perl5.8.8 and perl5.14.4. My perl script works fine with perl5.8.8 but give "Segmentation fault (Core dump) when I execute it with perl5.14.4. It looks like to me that the modules/library are not available to both the perl versions.
If my assumption is correct, how can I make it available to both the perl modules? 
I am seeing this issue in may linux systems where two different versions of perl are available. Though it works fine if I have only perl5.14.4 on that system. 
I tried getting the code dump using gdb, the output is something like this -
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/perl5.14.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

```
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libc.so.6" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libcrypto.so.6" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib/libz.so.1" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
Reading symbols from /lib/libnsl.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libnsl.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libdl.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
.
.
.
.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libkeyutils.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libresolv.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libresolv.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libselinux.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libselinux.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libsepol.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libsepol.so.1
Core was generated by `perl5.14.4 openwsman_client_FAN.pl'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

Different versions of Perl can't share XS libraries. If your vendor doesn't provide both versions of Perl with libraries for both of them, you have to compile them yourself. `cpan` should do the hard work for you.

[perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) can make life easier for you if you don't like playing with environment variables and cpan configs all the time.

Comment: Thanks.. is there a way I can build these libraries which can work with any version of perl.

Comment: @user1929570: No, it's not possible for XS libraries.